# what does this "=>" operator mean in C#?

Tags: c#

PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>

In the code snippet above what does this "=>" mean?
I have been unable to find any references for this

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its not always obvious however in this case its part of making a lamda peice of code, so rather than

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.Authenticate(something);
```

where something is declared as

```
bool something()
{
.. code ..
}
```

you can do something on the fly with

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => { .. code .. } );
```